# How do i unlabel a file using the TFS sdk and vb.net

Tags: vb.net, tfs-sdk

I'm in the process of writing a little app for our SQL developers to allow them to create labels with TFS for easy code deployment, the trouble is the .ssmssqlproj files are being added to the label when ever i create one. I've added a sub to loop through and unlabel these file but i just will not work. code below

```
  Public Sub UnlabelItem()


    Dim returnValue As LabelResult()
    Dim labelName As String = "1208-2210"
    Dim labelScope As String = "$/"
    Dim version As VersionSpec = New LabelVersionSpec(labelName, labelScope)

    Dim path As String = "$/FEPI/Database/FEPI/000 Pre Tasks.ssmssqlproj"
    Dim recursion As RecursionType = RecursionType.None

    Dim itemspec As ItemSpec = New ItemSpec(path, recursion)

    returnValue = sourceControl.UnlabelItem(labelName, labelScope, itemspec, version)


End Sub
```

this is a test Sub just to get it working and this is the error i get

Value of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ItemSpec' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ItemSpec'

HAs anybody had any luck with the unlabel command?

Matt